# Which windows vm allowed to upload to azure?

Tags: azure-virtual-machine

In Azure, I can upload VM from my local vhd. I find [Linux VM List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/endorsed-distros?toc=%2fazure%2fvirtual-machines%2flinux%2ftoc.json), but I can't find the Windows list.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the list too.
As far as I know, we can upload those windows version to Azure:

```
Server:
Windows server 2003
Windows server 2003 R2
Windows server 2008
Windows server 2008 R2
Windows server 2012
Windows server 2012 R2
Windows server 2016
Client:
Windows 7
Windows 8.1
Windows 10
```

> Windows Server
>
> Windows Server 2003 and later versions are supported for deployment in
>   Microsoft Azure.
>
> Client
>
> Certain versions of Windows 7, Windows 8.1, and Windows 10 are
>   available to MSDN Azure

More information please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/faq).

Comment: Please let me know if you would like further assistance.